# STL vector crash on push_back

Tags: c++, file, vector, stl

I'm writing a simple program that needs to manipulate arrays of bits. The arrays are loaded from a file using an ifstream; I simply read bytes from the file until I hit EOF, pushing each complete array onto a vector.

The crash I'm seeing is consistent: the 7th call to push_back on the vector fails, in the Release build only. In Debug, to contrast, we can read arrays indefinitely without ever hitting EOF. This would seem to imply some kind of memory screw up, but I don't see anything I'm obviously doing wrong. The crash happens regardless of the size of the array and regardless of whether or not I actually read anything from the file.

One caveat: I'm working here with a library that was provided with literally zero documentation. A prior developer had to reverse-engineer the API by dumping the strings from the DLL and doing a lot of experimentation (frankly I'm amazed we have something that works at all). So I'm willing to accept a possible explanation of "That library you're working with has hosed your stack", lacking any better ideas.

Anyway, here's the code:

```
std::vector<char*> bufList;
// Grab new buffer information from the file bufFilename.
void loadBuffers(int bufWidth, int bufHeight) {
    printf("Reloading buffers...\n");
    // First destroy old buffers, if applicable.
    if (!bufList.empty()) {
            for (std::vector<char*>::iterator i = bufList.begin(); i != bufList.end(); ++i) {
                    free(*i);
            }
    }
    bufList.clear();

    printf("bufList is empty now\n");

    // Read buffers from the file until we hit the end. Assume the file is properly formatted!
    // Also assume there is at least one buffer in the file.
    ifstream handle(bufFilename, ios::in | ios::binary);
    char* curBuffer;
    int numBuffers = 0;
    // One bit per pixel, ergo 8 pixels per byte.
    // NB implicit assumption that width * height is cleanly divisible by 8!
    int bufBytes = bufWidth * bufHeight / 8;
    printf("Each buffer needs %d bytes\n", bufBytes);
    while (TRUE) {
            printf("Loading buffer %d\n", numBuffers);
            // Allocate space for a new buffer.
            curBuffer = (char*) malloc(bufBytes);
            printf("Allocated buffer\n");
            // Read one buffer's worth of data from the handle.
            handle.read(curBuffer, bufBytes);
            printf("Read complete\n");
            // Assume if we hit EOF that there's no valid buffer.
            if (handle.eof()) {
                    printf("Hit EOF; free and break\n");
                    free(curBuffer);
                    break;
            }
            printf("Not done yet!\n");
            // Add the new buffer to the bufList.
            bufList.push_back(curBuffer);
            printf("Added buffer to vector; now are %d elements in vector.\n", bufList.size());
            numBuffers++;
    }
    handle.close();
    printf("Loaded %d buffers\n", numBuffers);
}
```

Comment: .... malloc and free? Why??

Comment: This: `(char*) malloc(bufBytes);` has no business being in a C++ program. And your `bufList` should be `std::vector<std::vector<unsigned char>>` if this does what I think it does, though frankly I don't understand why you're not just using `std::vector<unsigned char>` and reading the whole frame in at once.

Comment: Using `std::vector` does not convert magically your programming practices into C++ practices. **This is just C, masked with some bad ussage of C++ libraries**.

Comment: This: `printf("Added buffer to vector; now are %d elements in vector.\n", bufList.size());` might be problematic. `%d` expects a signed integer, but `bufList.size()` is probably a `size_t`.

Comment: Have you tried compiling with debug symbols?  What kind of crash is it?  On which line?